# How to override one page over other in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create pages which can override over another pages in React. Like see for an example here in Youtube: https://youtu.be/n5kr99DAjDk?t=441. The 'Post' page is opened with full height and a 'Back' button. This was easily possible in React Native. How could it be done in React for web.

Below is the code for reference:

App.js

```
const Routing = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <TopNavbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/newPage" component={NewPage} />
      </Switch>
      <BottomNavbar />
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "80px", position:'relative' }}>
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <Link to="/newPage">
        <button>Click Here</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

NewPage.js

```
const NewPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="newPageCSS">
      <h2>New Page</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewPage;
```

NewPage.css

```
.newPageCSS {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I have tried `position:absolute` in NewPage but, no use. What could be best possible solution?
Please have a look at the given below codesandbox link for clarity of code.
Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-9dodd

Comment: codesandbox app is breaking "Cannot read property 'getItem' of null". Looks like an issue with sessionStorage

Comment: OK please wait doing correction...

Comment: @Hyetigran Ya done changes... please check

Comment: @Hyetigran Have you found solution?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd like your new page component to take up all the room of the page except for top and bottom navigation.

The solution is entirely CSS, however you'll need to tinker with styles to get margins/padding correct. It looks like you're using a UI library which can clash with your style sheet.

Here are the changes:

Update your main container to use flexbox instead of trying to control for top/bottom navs with pixels

```
#root {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then, get your new page component to expand by adding a flex 1. Added red border to easily visualize change.

```
.newPageCSS {
    margin-top: 80px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Update your home page so bottom nav sticks to bottom and you can scroll home content

```
.homePageCSS {
    margin-top: 80px;
    max-height: 50%;
    /* position: relative; */
    flex: 1;
    max-height: 70vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Position fixed is now unnecessary for bottom nav

```
.makeStyles-gridList-2 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    /* bottom: 0px; */
    /* position: fixed; */
    padding: 0;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.... Only one doubt where to make use of #root? If you don't mind would you like to update in codesandbox

Comment: I believe you can add the #root style to your index.css file. The div you're attaching your react app already exists which you can find the the index.html file in your public directory.

Comment: Ok will try the solution... Thanks again

Comment: I have tried... but, not as expected... Can you update in my codesandbox